# How can I allow only flash activeX but others disallow in my webcontrol used IWebBrowser2?

Tags: c++, com, mfc, web-controls

I am working on my webcontrol used IWebBrowser2.

I want it play flash movie but disallow other ActiveX controls.
I found disallow all ActiveX contorls using DLCTL_NO_DLACTIVEXCTLS | DLCTL_NO_RUNACTIVEXCTLS flags
in implements of invoke.
but I've searching msdn for IWebBrowser and related Interfaces, I can't found any solution.

I expect catch a event before ActiveX loaded or allow only flash ActiveX ways.

please help. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Hosts of the Web Browser can control how it behaves by implementing IOleClientSite and responding to DISPID_AMBIENT_DLCONTROL with a set of desired behavior flags. One important caveat: the flag DLCTL_NO_RUNACTIVEXCTLS only blocks OBJECT tags within the document itself. It has no impact on the use of calls to new ActiveXObject(“…”) from script, if DLCTL_NO_SCRIPTS was not set.

In order to prevent ActiveX execution in a Web Browser host, supply an IInternetSecurityManager and return URLPOLICY_DISALLOW and S_FALSE when your ProcessURLAction implementation is called with URLACTION_ACTIVEX_RUN. To permit only a specified “allow list” of controls to run, the ProcessURLAction implementation can examine the CLSID of the requested control; that CLSID is passed in using the pContext parameter.